# Java, Stanford NLP : Unable to validate jar entry per:countries_of_residence.rules on Windows only

Tags: java, windows, parsing, stanford-nlp

I am working on integrating Stanford NLP 3.7.0 on our system and we have no problem on Linux system, but windows development machine is facing a problem. I have added Stanford-parser and its Javadoc in classpath, and models is part of maven. THis is the error we get when we start the project :

Error log :

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to validate JAR entry with name edu/stanford/nlp/models/kbp/tokensregex/per:countries_of_residence.rules

                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3359)

                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResource(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1424)

                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.getResourceAsStream(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1652)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.findStreamInClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:407)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.getInputStreamFromURLOrClasspathOrFileSystem(IOUtils.java:461)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.io.IOUtils.readStreamFromString(IOUtils.java:390)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromSerializedFile(LexicalizedParser.java:601)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.getParserFromFile(LexicalizedParser.java:405)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:187)

                at edu.stanford.nlp.parser.lexparser.LexicalizedParser.loadModel(LexicalizedParser.java:166)

                at com.tooltank.spring.service.GroupCanvasServiceImpl.<init>(GroupCanvasServiceImpl.java:56)

                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)

                at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)

                at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)

                at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Die Syntax für den Dateinamen, Verzeichnisnamen oder die Datenträgerbezeichnung ist falsch

                at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)

                at java.io.WinNTFileSystem.canonicalize(WinNTFileSystem.java:428)

                at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:618)

                at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findResourceInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3352)
```

POM.xml :

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>


     <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
        </dependency>
```

Any ideas? THank you.

*Solution*

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
                    <artifactId>stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models-kbp</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a known issue where the file names for some KBP relation extractor resources don't work on Windows.  They were made with ":" in them which is bad on Windows.  We are going to at some point change them to something more Windows friendly.  If you don't use the KBP annotator on Windows I think this issue would go away, you might also need to exclude the stanford-corenlp-3.7.0-models-kbp.jar.

Comment: Hi, We are getting GC overhead when using NLP, I have posted a question regarding the same. Can you please check : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42690737/standford-nlp-gc-overhead-limit-excedded-when-using-parser-on-tomcat   . Thank you.

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp The solution you have mentioned did not work for me, it downloads a single jar called models and these kbp packages are there inside that. Any suggestions?