# Stanford-NLP : GC overhead limit excedded when using parser on Tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, garbage-collection, stanford-nlp

We are working on integrating Stanford NLP on our system and it is working fine, just that it causes `gc overhead limit exceeded`. WE have the memory dump and will analyze it, but if ányone has some idea about this issue, please let us know. The server is quite powerful, SSD, 32gb RAM, Xeon E5 series.

Code we have:

```
 String text = Jsoup.parse(groupNotes.getMnotetext()).text();
                String lang;
                try {
                    DetectorFactory.clear();
                    DetectorFactory.loadProfile("/home/deploy/profiles/");
                    Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create();
                    detector.append(text);
                     lang = detector.detect();
                }catch (Exception ignored){
                    lang = "de";
                }

                LexicalizedParser lp;
                if (lang.toLowerCase().equals("de")) {
                    lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(GERMAN_PCG_MODEL);
                } else {
                    lp = LexicalizedParser.loadModel(ENGLISH_PCG_MODEL);
                }
                Tree parse;
                parse = lp.parse(text);
                List<String> stringList = new ArrayList<>();
                List taggedWords = parse.taggedYield();
               // System.out.println(taggedWords);
                for (Object str : taggedWords) {
                    if (str.toString().contains("NN")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/NN", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("NNS")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/NNS", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("NNP")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/NNP", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("NNPS")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/NNPS", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VB")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VB", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VBD")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VBD", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VBG")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VBG", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VBN")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VBN", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VBZ")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VBZ", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("VBP")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/VBP", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("JJ")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/JJ", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("JJR")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/JJR", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("JJS")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/JJS", ""));
                    }
                    if (str.toString().contains("FW")) {
                        stringList.add(str.toString().replace("/FW", ""));
                    }
                }
```

JVM options for Apache tomcat :

```
CATALINA_OPTS="$CATALINA_OPTS -server -Xms2048M -Xmx3048M -XX:OnOutOfMemoryError="/home/deploy/scripts/tomcatrestart.sh" -XX:+UseParallelGC -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemory -XX:HeapDumpPath=/path/to/date.hprof -XX:-UseGCOverheadLimit -Dspring.security.strategy=MODE_INHERITABLETHREADLOCAL"
```

Any ideas?

POM.xml :

```
  <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <classifier>models</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
            <classifier>models-german</classifier>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
 <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-parser</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>


     <dependency>
            <groupId>edu.stanford.nlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>stanford-corenlp</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.0</version>
         <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: How long is the text that is causing the crash?  If you feed a very long sentence to the parser it can take up a huge amount of memory that will cause a crash.

Comment: Also I would suggest moving to the pipeline API instead of directly using LexicalizedParser.  Here is some documentation: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html

Comment: @StanfordNLPHelp : The text can be very long, even in paragraphs. I am checki out the API now. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Just to clarify something, `lp.parse(...)` should be running on a sentence, not a paragraph or document.  `lp.parse(...)` takes in a sentence and returns the parse tree for the sentence.  You will definitely have crash issues if you run it on a paragraph or document length text.  If you use the pipeline API you can also set the maximum length sentence the parsing will run on and if you hand in a longer sentence than that you will just get a flat parse.  Often times in real-world NLP you will run into huge sentences which are just lists of things and it's helpful to just skip these since the parser will crash on them.  As I noted in the comments you can learn more about the pipeline API here: http://stanfordnlp.github.io/CoreNLP/api.html